# Using system() to copy a file (with "cp") never returns?

Tags: c, system

```
char cmd[256];
memset(cmd,0,256);
sprintf(cmd, "cp %s %s", "test1.txt", "test2.txt");
system(cmd);
printf("cmd completed\n");
```

When I run the above code, my application hangs at system call. I never get to the printf line. I am running on Linux Centos with GCC compiler.

Any help is appreciated.

If i run the above code in a separate application (copy paste in the main). It runs fine.

Comment: I recommend attaching in gdb and seeing where the program is hanging - that should point you to what is wrong.

Comment: You should put in a complete, compilable example, including the definition of `BUFSIZ` and any #includes.

Comment: It could be waiting for user input

Comment: BUFSIZ is in `<stdio.h>` which is included because he's using `sprintf()`.  Similarly, `<string.h>` and `<stdlib.h>` should be included.

Comment: @dbeer I did attach it to the debugger. In fact that is how i found out that application is getting stuck at system call line.

Comment: @user1330023 As per m0skit0's comment, does "test2.txt" exist already? Does it "not hang" when using the `-f` option of "cp"?

Comment: Use `gdb` and/or `strace` to find out where the process(es) launched by `system` hang(s). Normally there should be two processes, the shell and `cp` itself. `strace -f <yourprogram>` is probably the easiest way.

Comment: According to the linux man page, `system()` passes your command into `/bin/sh -c`.  Does anyone know if its possible `/bin/sh` is really aliasing `cp` to `cp -n`?

Comment: Maybe see the return value code from `system()` function say something for you.

Answer (score 7):

As a complete program, the code below works just fine under most conditions.

The only way I can get it to hang is if `test1.txt` is a special file type that causes `cp` to hang.  For example `mkfifo test1.txt` will give you funny results.  And by funny results, I mean you have to kill the program with a CTRL+C, kill, etc.

Your problem is most likely not in the code you've posted.

```
/* copy.c, 
   compile using the command "gcc -o copy copy.c"
   run using "./copy"
*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

#define CMD_SIZE 256
char cmd[CMD_SIZE];

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
  memset( cmd, 0, CMD_SIZE );
  sprintf( cmd, "cp %s %s", "test1.txt", "test2.txt" );
  system(cmd);
  printf("cmd complete\n");
}
```

As a sanity check, you might try adding `printf("%d\n", BUFSIZE)` to check the value of `BUFSIZE` and `printf("%s\n", cmd)` to make sure the command really looks like what you want it to.

Comment: You don't need do the implicit `memset()` call. The `sprintf()` function, format and put the null byte,'\0', into EOS string.

Comment: @Jack, Yeah, I know.   Also, to be thorough, `sprintf` should be `snprintf`.  And `main` should return something. And `cmd` should not be global. And the return values of `snprintf` and `system` should both be checked.  The goal was not to write production code, but to replicate the OP's code in a standalone program.